# Restart LAN connection when network is down

Tags: windows

Could someone guide me creating a script to restart LAN connection (i.e : disable then enable) when the network is down?

I think the general ideas, is to ping Google, then if the connection is `RTO` more than 3-5 times, then restart the LAN. Like this maybe?

```
ping www.google.com -t
net stop netman
net start netman
```

How do I put this into a script?

Sorry forgot something, the OS is win xp